# R : Reading KMZ and appending geography to polygon from png

Tags: r, polygon, kml, png

Question: How do I make a png embedded within a kmz useable as a polygon?

Context:
I am trying to read a KMZ file generated by a [free 3rd party tool](https://ispdesign.ui.com/) and to make the .png image within useable as a polygon for the purpose of intersecting with other sf data. An example KMZ from the tool using downtown Melbourne can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gVGREmB2I1UETSGHMQ9EVmFmSKFZj3cr/view?usp=sharing)

I am using a combination of [this advice](https://gist.github.com/valentinitnelav/0f89f9cad2c7bcae8f989f0cd90bb395) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68582979/is-there-a-way-to-transform-a-png-icon-to-a-sf-multipolygon-in-r) since I will have multiples of these to extract, however I am just focusing on getting it to work for file one at the moment.

This is where I have gotten to so far:

Code for extracting KMZ which is working OK

```
# extract long-lat coordinates from a bunch of kmz files
# first unzips the KMZ-s then reads coordinates from each KML with getKMLcoordinates {maptools}

library(maptools)

# list the kmz files in a given folder path
KMZs <- list.files(path="Projects/Oneoffs/SQ/Heat_kmz/", pattern="*.kmz", full.names=FALSE)

# unzip each KMZ file and read coordinates with getKMLcoordinates()
# select only the matrix element of the list returned by getKMLcoordinates(), 
# therefore mention the index [[1]]
sapply(KMZs,function(x)unzip(zipfile = paste0("Projects/Oneoffs/SQ/Heat_kmz/", x),exdir =paste0("Projects/Oneoffs/SQ/Heat_kmz/KML/",x)))
LonLat<-sapply(KMZs,function(x)getKMLcoordinates(kmlfile=paste0("Projects/Oneoffs/SQ/Heat_kmz/KML/",x,"/doc.kml"),ignoreAltitude = TRUE)[[1]])
# To get altitude from KML, then mention ignoreAltitude=FALSE                

# delete the .kmz part from the column names in LonLat matrix
colnames(LonLat) <- gsub(pattern=".kmz", replacement="", x=colnames(LonLat))
# give names to rows
rownames(LonLat) <- c("longitude", "latitude")
# transpose the matrix for readability reasons
LonLat <- t(LonLat)
#make sf
LonLat <- st_as_sf(as.data.frame(LonLat),coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)
#associate to file
```

and the code for polygonizing the .png file within

```
#attempt to draw on png
library(terra)
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(raster)

rast("Projects/Oneoffs/SQ/Heat_kmz/KML/101.kmz/files/coverage-ffa95122-414d-489c-8112-8bb930f13952.png") %>% 
  .[[1:4]] %>% 
  {. ->> heat_101}

heat_101 %>% 
  as.polygons %>% 
  st_as_sf %>%
  rename(
    value = 1
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> heat_101_multipoly}
#extract kml to test
st_write(heat_101_multipoly, dsn="Projects/Oneoffs/SQ/heat_101_multipoly.kml", layer= "geometry", driver="KML")
```

I have put the resulting kml in to google earth and the results are an odd globe-spanning shape.

I somehow need to associate the co-ordinate from the first code part to this png and then scale the polygon accordingly. I think the answer is something to do with maptools:elide but I am drawing a blank in finding similar solutions on the web.

Comment: Heyo Mark. It could be nice if you can clarify your question to make it easier to answer by asking a very simple question with a question mark. Now a problem is stated, but it might not be very clear to people what question you want to have answered.

Comment: Thank you at @Davma, edited!

Comment: @hugh-allan I was hoping somehow I'd be able to do this from your answer regarding the ship but I'm still struggling at the point of assigning any geometry to the png layer

Comment: Your note about the “odd globe spanning shape” sounds suspiciously like a projection issue. I have experienced similar when trying to load KMLs into GoogleEarth that have a CRS other than WGS84. Are you certain your KML output is in WGS84?